Laravel: Issues with Adding Multiple Images to an Existing Collection
I'm working with a Laravel application where I need to manage multiple image uploads for an existing project. I'm trying to update the image list by first deleting old images from storage, then adding the paths of these old images to a new array along with the paths of newly uploaded images. However, when I upload new images and attempt to update the array that holds the image paths, I encounter an issue where the existing image paths return as an empty string in the format [{}, "new_image_path"].
Additionally, I've tried using json_decode on the array, but I get an error saying json_decode(): Argument #1 ($json) must be of type string, array given.
$pricelists = [];
$pricelistcount = 1;
if ($request->hasFile('project_pricelist_url')) {

    $existingPricelists = $project->project_pricelist_url ?: [];
        foreach ($existingPricelists as $existingPricelist) {
            Storage::delete('public/project/pricelists/' . $existingPricelist);
        }

        foreach ($existingPricelists as $existingFilename) {
            $pricelists[] = $existingFilename; // Add existing filenames to the new array
        }





    foreach ($request->file('project_pricelist_url') as $file) {
        $currentDateTime = now()->format('YmdHis');
        $filename = $initials . "_" . $pricelistcount . '_' . $currentDateTime . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension(); // Buat nama unik untuk setiap file
        $file->storeAs('public/project/pricelists', $filename); // Simpan file ke direktori yang diinginkan
        $pricelistcount++;
        $pricelists[] = $filename; // Simpan nama file dalam array
    }
    $project->project_pricelist_url =  json_encode($pricelists);

}

How can I correctly manage and update the list of image paths during the upload process to ensure both old and new image paths are retained and formatted correctly?

Can you explain more what you want to do ?

@xenooooo i want to append new image path instead of just replacing all existing images

Do you store the image paths inside the database in one column ?

complete ternary operator have only else part,
try this below code, hope this helps
if ($request->hasFile('project_pricelist_url')) {
   $existingPricelists = !empty($project->project_pricelist_url) ? $project->project_pricelist_url : [];
   $pricelists = [];

    foreach ($existingPricelists as $existingPricelist) {
        $existingFilename = $existingPricelist;
        $pricelists[] = $existingFilename; // Add existing filenames to the new array
        Storage::delete('public/project/pricelists/' . $existingPricelist);
    }

    // remove second loop

    $files = $request->file('project_pricelist_url');
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        $currentDateTime = now()->format('YmdHis');
        $filename = $initials . "_" . $pricelistcount . '_' . $currentDateTime . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension(); // Buat nama unik untuk setiap file
        $file->storeAs('public/project/pricelists', $filename); // Simpan file ke direktori yang diinginkan
        $pricelistcount++;

        $pricelists[] = $filename; // Simpan nama file dalam array
    }
    
    $project->project_pricelist_url = json_encode($pricelists);
}


the result i get in column is
[{}, "rg_1_20240712150824.jpg"]
and second when i change from StoreAs to move, the file doesnt even being stored, and couldnt find the image.

@MartinusGoh removed second loop, and changed move() to storeAs() as you said move() is not working in your case. Also check old images are deleting ?
